# Not able to get user media permission even after allowing media permission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, media-queries

I'm creating a webrtc based video conferencing web.

<kbd>SocketContext</kbd>

```
 useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
      .then((currentStream) => {
        setStream(currentStream);

        myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Not able to get user media permisiion");
      })

    socket.on('me', (id) => setMe(id));

    socket.on('callUser', ({ from, name: callerName, signal }) => {
      setCall({ isReceivingCall: true, from, name: callerName, signal });
    });
  }, []);
```

So even after giving permission to browser, I'm getting an error of `Not able to get user media permission` and myVideo is also null;

Comment: in which line number ? can you paste your console error message over here

Comment: you need to reload component once you get permission might be it work

Comment: no , its not working even after reloading